# React.js: как при клике на элемент добавлять ему класс?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть такой код:

```
crateDropDownList: function () {
    var dropDownBrandClass = this.state.checkedBrand ? 'active' : '';

    return ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item, i) {
        return <li className={dropDownBrandClass} onClick={this.checkBrand.bind(this, item)} key={i}><a href="#">{item}</a></li>
    }.bind(this));
},
```

тут я создаю меню из трех элементов, теперь при клике на один из элементов я хочу добавить пункту, на который кликнул, класс.

```
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        checkedBrand: false
    }
},

checkBrand: function (event) {
    this.setState({
        checkedBrand: !this.state.checkedBrand
    });

},
```

Но проблема в том, что класс добавляется всем пунктам меню.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавлять класс именно тому пункту, на котором произошло событие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> onClick={this.checkBrand.bind(this, item)}
> checkBrand: function (event) {
> ```

В этих местах надо быть намного внимательнее.

Как минимум, event придёт вторым параметром, а item первым.

Далее, что вообще оказывается this'ом при такой привязке?